# Access properties in model - C#

Tags: c#, json, model, properties

I'll try keep this simple

I am trying to access the highlighted properties in this model:

[image]

As you can see, I can access the properties in CreateNewLookup ok but am struggling with accessing the ones in LookupValue

[image]

This needs to be serialized back to the following JSON format (below). I know how to do this I am just stuck with how to access it as above:

[image]

This is the code that is causing me the issue:

```
        private static CreateNewLookup DefaultNewLookuptRecord => new CreateNewLookup()
    {
        Reference = "TestRef",
        Label = "City",
        LookupValues = new LookupValue
        {
            Tenant = "9",
            Label = "London",
            Value = "London",
            IsActive = true,
        }
    };
```

It is probably really simple, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: In the json example "lookupValues" is an array, in the C# it is a single object

Answer (score 1):

`LookupValues` is declared as an array.

If you look at the actual error message rather than stop at the squiggly red lines, the same will probably be pointed out in there.

Therefore, instead of assigning a new `LookupValue` instance

```
new LookupValue { ... }
```

assign an array with a new lookup value instance:

```
new[] { new LookupValue { ... }}
```

Comment: I see now yes, thank you